# Правописание приставки «нано»

Tags: орфография, приставка, приставки

Никак не могу понять, в какие моменты «нано» писать с дефисом, а в какие — слитно.

Вот есть такие слова:

- Нано-инфузор
- Нано-рост
- Нано-кинжал
- Нано-меч
- Нанобот
- Нанотех
- Нанотехнологическая инженерия
- Нанотехнологии
- Наноматериалы
- Нанометр

Я начал думать, что если «нано» используется для характеризации предмета, типа «нано-меч» пишется с дефисом, так как признаком меча было его создание с помощью наноботов.
«Нанобот» пишется слитно, так как это это что-то маленькое, *нано*.
«Нанотехнологии» пишется слитно, так как без «нано» слово «технологии» потеряет изначальный смысл того, что это наука о наномашинах.

И кажется, что тут могут появиться противоречия по типу «нано-технологии» или «наномеч».

Так вот: КАК ЖЕ ПИСАТЬ ПРАВИЛЬНО?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что все слова должны писаться **слитно**, что видно по словарю. **Исключения** встречаются редко.

**[Справочная служба Грамота.ру](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE&mode=spravka)** отвечает так:

Первая часть сложных слов **нано**... **пишется слитно** (в том числе и при **окказиональном** употреблении).

[**Русский орфографический словарь**](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=71&dicts%5B%5D=42)

**нано**... – первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно, но: **нано-арт.**

**Большой толковый словарь русского языка**

**НАНО...** [греч. nános - карлик]. Первая часть сложных слов. Спец. Вносит зн.: равный одной миллиардной доле единицы, указанной во второй части слова (для наименования единиц физических величин). Нанограмм, нанометр.

**№ 264164**
Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пишется частица "нано-" с существительными. Я всегда была уверена, что слитно, но недавно увидела вывеску **"НАНО_МОЙКА"** (с пробелом, написано раздельно). Это ошибка?

**ОТВЕТ.**
Да, это ошибка. Первая часть сложных слов нано... пишется слитно (в том числе и при подобном окказиональном употреблении).

Comment: Думаю, что так и буду писать слитно. Так будет намного легче.

Однако я также нашёл статью на тему "Проблемы письменной адаптации производных с морфемой _нано-_". Вот [ссылка](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/problemy-pismennoy-adaptatsii-proizvodnyh-s-morfemoy-nano/viewer) на неё.
В конце было сказано следующее: все слова с нано-, за исключением аналитического прилагательного нано, следует писать слитно, что сняло бы орфографическое противоречие.

Стоит ли этому верить?

Comment: Если говорить о нормированном  письме, то формант нано-  как самостоятельное слово не употребляется, и, как мне кажется, ситуация  в ближайшее время не изменится. Дефисное написание также маловероятно, за исключением слов типа нон-арт из двух иноязычных элементов. Поэтому надо писать слитно. В ПАС даются правила  для таких сложных слов http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=65  Что касается ненормированной орфографии, то она существует, но там свои законы. Если слова нет в словаре, то пишут как кому нравится.